# Which name for method that sends and persist some messages would you recommend?

Tags: naming

I'm writing notification system and faced a challenge of how to name an API for sending notifications over network, that will also save ones into a database. Imagine that we don't need to distinguish those two responsibilities in own methods.

I've came up with the idea of "publish", however I think this decision is biased.

Which one would you recommend?

Comment: I've an API with a route like that. We named it `notifications/push`.